# Shopify Get resourse_type at first when redirected to my application

Tags: shopify

My application is complete and work perfectly for **Products**.

Like i have an "application link" in the Products tab.On clicking, i get the **SHOP** name and **ID** of that product.Then i can successfully call the API because

GET /admin/products/#{id}/XXXX.json

by default i had use the "products" in path resolution.

Now the question is, **at first** I only got the **ID** with query parameter but don't know from which resource_type this belongs? i.e pages,themes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this problem is that "you can append parameters to your query string" in Application Links.